# Find summation of the series (PDE approach)

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, summation, exponential-function

The summation is given as:
$$
\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{a^j e^{-\frac{b}{j}}}{j!}
$$
where $a>1$ and $b>1$

This question actually arises when you try to find the sum over the product of two functions:

1. a poisson distribution
   $$
   \frac{a^j} {j!} e^{-a}
   $$
2. a j-times convolved gaussian function
   $$
   \underbrace{e^{-px^2}\circledast e^{-px^2}\circledast\cdots\circledast e^{-px^2} }_{\text{j times}}= e^{-\frac{p}{j}x^2}=e^{-\frac{b}{j}}
   $$

Can it be solved as follows:

$$
y=\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{a^j e^{-\frac{b}{j}}}{j!}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial b}=\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{a^j e^{-\frac{b}{j}}\cdot\frac{-1}{j}}{j!}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}(\frac{\partial y}{\partial b})=\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{j\cdot a^{j-1} e^{-\frac{b}{j}}\cdot\frac{-1}{j}}{j!}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}(\frac{\partial y}{\partial b})=-\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{a^{j-1} e^{-\frac{b}{j}}}{j!}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}(\frac{\partial y}{\partial b})=-\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{a^{j-1} e^{-\frac{b}{j}}}{j!} \cdot \frac{a}{a}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}(\frac{\partial y}{\partial b})=-\frac{1}{a}\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{a^{j} e^{-\frac{b}{j}}}{j!}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}(\frac{\partial y}{\partial b})=\frac{-y}{a}
$$
How should I solve this PDE?

Comment: Thanks @insipidintegrator

Comment: You should be using partial derivatives. You've also lost a $-$ sign.

Comment: Thanks @J.G. 
correction done.

Comment: Is there a reason to think that there is a closed form for this series?

Comment: How do you go from $\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial a\partial b}=-\frac{y}{a}$ to $y=a^{-b}$? This contradicts the boundary condition $\left.y\right|_{b=0}=1-e^{-a}$.

Comment: Is there a good way to solve this type of pde?  I tried separation of variables but could not get separation of $a$ dependence and $b$ dependence.

Comment: Now that I looked at it, whatever i did doesn't make any sense. All I need to solve this pde and would be nice if someone could help.

Comment: By changing co-ordinates, your PDE may be cast in the form of the Helmholtz equation. A solution by (for example) separation of variables is possible. The final answer, after taking the Fourier transform of the initial condition (and derivative..) will be in the form of an infinite sum, which is not likely to be any simpler than your first sum

Comment: Would you please show a few steps, anyway? @Sal

Comment: Let $a=e^x$ so that $a\partial_a=\partial_x$, then we have $\partial_{xb}y=-y$. Then let $\chi=x+b$, $\eta=x-b$ and we have $(\partial_{\chi \chi}-\partial_{\eta \eta})y=-y$

Comment: Further to @Sal's point, if we write $y$ as a function $y(\chi,\,\eta)$, the boundary condition I mentioned before is now $y(x,\,x)=1-e^{-e^{x}}$.